# Error System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Error converting data type nvarchar to numeric.' in c#

Tags: c#, sql

I'm inserting data from one database table to another with a buttonclick and this error shows up System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: `'Error converting data type nvarchar to numeric.' in both tables the data types matches.`

The data types are id = int, Druh = varchar(50), Nazov = varchar(50), Cena = numeric(18,2). I think the problem is with the "Cena".`

```
 using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constring))
                {
                    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO stol2 VALUES(@id,@Druh, @Nazov, @Cena)", con))
                    {
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", row.Cells["Column2"].Value);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Druh", row.Cells["Column3"].Value);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Nazov", row.Cells["Column4"].Value);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Cena", row.Cells["Column5"].Value);
                        con.Open();
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        con.Close();
```

Comment: Debug your code, what is the value of `row.Cells["Column5"].Value`

Comment: Most probably you are assigning a string value to a column which should be numeric.

Comment: Check if row.Cells["Column5"].Value contains null or empty values

Comment: Try storing your `row.Cells["ColumnNo"].Value` in variables with the correct data types (`decimal` for Cena). Then pass those variables to the `cmd` parameters. (You will need to use `decimal.Parse(row.Cells["Column5"].Value)` to store as decimal)

Comment: The value of `row.Cells["Column5"].Value` is 1,00

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try parse before using value for preventing `Exception` like this

```
decimal Cena;
int id;
var validCena = decimal.TryParse(row.Cells["Column5"].Value.ToString(), out Cena);
var validId = int.TryParse(row.Cells["Column2"].Value.ToString(), out id);

if(validCena && validId)
{
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Druh", row.Cells["Column3"].Value);
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Nazov", row.Cells["Column4"].Value);
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Cena", Cena);

   con.Open();
   cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
   con.Close();
}
```